# using state in python generator comprehensions?

Tags: python, generator

Is there any way to convert this generator function into a relatively simple generator comprehension? (the following works for me, I just want to understand what possible options are)

```
def annotate(x):
   n = 0
   for item in x:
     yield(item,n)
     n = n + 1
```

use example:

```
>>> for line in annotate([3,4,5]):
...   print line
...
(3, 0)
(4, 1)
(5, 2)
```

Comment: You mean like `enumerate()`? or maybe `zip()`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
comp = ((y,x) for x,y in enumerate(iterable))
```

demonstration:

```
>>> annotated = ((y,x) for x,y in enumerate(range(1,4)))
>>> for line in annotated: print line
... 
(1, 0)
(2, 1)
(3, 2)
```

Although, usually you'd only use `enumerate` and just unpack in the opposite order. :^)

Comment: sweet! I wasn't expecting an answer, nice to see that there is one :-)